# Linked list that I made in Java throwing OutOfMemory error

Tags: java, linked-list, jvm, out-of-memory

Here I tried to implement Linked List code in Java but it is giving me Out of memory exception
*Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space*, I found while debugging that next of first is pointing to first only and not able to find where this is coming. While debugging in add method it is showing proper link list but it is different when it gets back to main method, can anyone please help me in this.

```
public class LinkedListSolution {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
            LinkedList list = new LinkedList();
            list.add(1);
            list.add(6);
            list.add(2);
            list.add(3);
            list.add(4);
       }
}
class LinkedList{
    Node first;
    public void add(Integer element){
      Node last;
      if(first == null){
          first = new Node();
          first.element = element;
          first.next = null;
      }else{
          last = first;
          while(last.next != null){
            last = last.next;
          }
          Node node = new Node();
          node.element = element;
          last.next = node;
      }
    }
}

class Node{
    Integer element;
    Node next;
}
```

Comment: Couldn't reproduce

Comment: I did this in Java 8 version jdk1.8.0_141

Comment: To second @JCWasmx86, see https://ideone.com/2zJbew Runs without problems.

Comment: Couldn't reproduce